# asp.net mvc partial pages in layout not responsive

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, sass

I have partial views in my layout for Sidebar,TopNavigation(header),Right Bar(Chat bar) and footer(media player). I have just laid colored the background of each section to highlight the difference. I am not good in UI and new to MVC. The layout page is unresponsive as shown below

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Dam.jpg)

[Unresponsive landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqLks.jpg)

```
    <div id="left" style="width: 20%; background: red;float:left;height:auto">
        @Html.Partial("_SideBar")

    </div>

    <div id="right" style="width: 20%; background: green;float:right;height:auto;">
        @Html.Partial("_ChatBar")
    </div>
    <div id="header" style="position: absolute;width:55%; top: 0; left: 20%; right: 0; height: 30px; background: blue;">
        @Html.Partial("_TopNav")
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="width:60%;background: lime;float:left;height:auto;">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="width:100%;background:none;clear:both;position:fixed;top:auto;bottom:0px;visibility: visible;display: block;left:0px;right:0px;">
        @Html.Partial("_fullPlayer")
    </div>
</div>
```

_SideBar.cshtml

```
<!-- Sidebar Holder -->
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">

        @Html.Partial("_Weather")
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                Home
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="~/Albums/Index.cshtml"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
                About
            </a>
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
                Pages
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i>
                Portfolio
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>
                FAQ
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
                Contact
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

_TopNav.cshtml

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="~/Content/Album/css/ticker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       function createTicker(data) {
            $(container).append(
                '<li class="list-group-item">' +
                '<span class="badge">' + data.name + '-' + data._embedded.venues[0].city.name + ',' + data._embedded.venues[0].state.stateCode + ',' + data._embedded.venues[0].country.countryCode + '</span>' +
                '<a href=' + data.url + '></a>' +
                '</li>'
            );
        }

        function recursiveGetProp(obj, lookup, callback) {
            for (property in obj) {
                if (property === lookup) {
                    callback(obj[property]);
                } else if (obj[property] instanceof Object) {
                    recursiveGetProp(obj[property], lookup, callback);
                }
            }
        }


        var appKey = "xbpEva5O0SOLwPxCONoGfmywOnRwVTvS";
        var artist = "taylor swift";
        var events = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=" + appKey + "&keyword='" + artist + "'"
        debugger;

        var e = "https://cybup.blogspot.com",
            t = 20;
        $.ajax({
            url: events,
            //type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                function t() {



                    $("#adbreakingnews li:first").slideUp(function () {
                        $(this)
                            .appendTo($("#adbreakingnews ul"))
                            .slideDown();
                    });
                }
                var n,
                    b,
                    r,
                    s = "",
                    a = data;
                if (void 0 !== a) {
                    if (a._embedded.events.length > 1) {

                        recursiveGetProp(a, 'events', function (obj) {
                            if (obj !== null) {
                                s = "<ul>";

                                $.each(obj, function (i) {
                                    b = obj[i].name + '-' + obj[i]._embedded.venues[0].city.name + ',' + obj[i]._embedded.venues[0].state.stateCode + ',' + obj[i]._embedded.venues[0].country.countryCode;
                                    (r = b),

                                        (s += '<li> <a href="' + obj[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + r + "</a></li> ");

                                    // createTicker(obj[i]);
                                });

                                (s += "</ul>"),
                                    $("#adbreakingnews").html(s),
                                    setInterval(function () {
                                        t();
                                    }, 5e3);

                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else $("#adbreakingnews").html("<span>No result!</span>");

            },
            error: function () {
                $("#adbreakingnews").html("<strong>Error Loading Feed!</strong>");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="headerTop">
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
        </button>

    </div>

    <div id="breakingnews">
        <span class="breakhead"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>
        <div id="adbreakingnews">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_ChatBar.cshtml

```
<div id="divContainer" class="aside-md bg-light dk">
<h4 class="font-thin m-l-md m-t">Connected</h4>

<div id="divLogin" class="login">
    <div>
        Your Name:<br />
        <input id="txtNickName" style="color:black;" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="divButton">
        <input id="btnStartChat" style="color:black;" type="button" class="submitButton" value="Start Chat" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divChat" class="chatRoom">
    <div class="title">
        Welcome to Chat Room [<span id='spanUser'></span>]
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="divChatWindow" class="chatWindow">
        </div>
        <div id="divusers" class="users">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="messageBar">
        <input type="text" id="txtMessage" />
        <input id="btnSendMsg" type="button" value="Send" class="submitButton" />
    </div>
</div>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
```

_fullmediaplayer.cshtml

```
<footer class="footer">
<div id="mediawrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <audio id="mejsAudio" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" width="100%" height="30px" style="max-width: 100%; max-height:30px">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/9ucf2r3yo6/chasing_cars_cover_chris_-_for_hollie_s_cover.mp3" title="Chasing Corporate" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <source src="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3" title="Air Review - Chasing Corporate">
        <source src="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-04-AllBecauseYoureMine.mp3" title="Air Review - All Because You're Mine">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/9ucf2r3yo6/chasing_cars_cover_chris_-_for_hollie_s_cover.mp3" title="Chris - Chasing Cars(Cover)">
        <source src="http://k004.kiwi6.com/hotlink/vvy55kc7c5/new_distance.mp3" title="SmallCityLights - New Distance">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/0c2q7je6rn/i_got_you.mp3" title="Jamie Ray - I got you">
        <source src="http://k006.kiwi6.com/hotlink/081qjgl6pt/when_you_re_gone_cover_chris_.mp3" title="Chris - When You're Gone Cover">
        <source src="http://www.miaowmusic.com/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" title="Miaow - Bubble">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/9ucf2r3yo6/chasing_cars_cover_chris_-_for_hollie_s_cover.mp3" title="Chasing Corporate" type="audio/mpeg" />

        <source src="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3" title="Air Review - Chasing Corporate">
        <source src="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-04-AllBecauseYoureMine.mp3" title="Air Review - All Because You're Mine">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/9ucf2r3yo6/chasing_cars_cover_chris_-_for_hollie_s_cover.mp3" title="Chris - Chasing Cars(Cover)">
        <source src="http://k004.kiwi6.com/hotlink/vvy55kc7c5/new_distance.mp3" title="SmallCityLights - New Distance">
        <source src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/0c2q7je6rn/i_got_you.mp3" title="Jamie Ray - I got you">
        <source src="http://k006.kiwi6.com/hotlink/081qjgl6pt/when_you_re_gone_cover_chris_.mp3" title="Chris - When You're Gone Cover">
        <source src="http://www.miaowmusic.com/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" title="Miaow - Bubble">
    </audio>
</div>
</footer>
```

SideBar.css

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i, span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*background: #7386D5;*/
    background: #181f24;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3, #sidebar.active .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

    #sidebar.active ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, #sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #68696b;
}

    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
        /*color: #7386D5;*/
        color: #181f24;
        background: #fff;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #181f24;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}

/*sub-menu*/
ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    /*background: #6d7fcc;*/
    background: #68696b;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    /*color: #7386D5;*/
    color: #181f24;
}

a.article, a.article:hover {
    /*background: #6d7fcc !important;*/
    background: #7386D5 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }

    a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 5px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3, #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

ChatStyle.css

```
body {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
}

#header {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #d7e5e4;
    border-bottom: #5f9482 solid 2px;
    color: #1e4638;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.submitButton {
    background-color: #d7e5e4;
    border: #5f9482 solid 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .submitButton:hover {
        background-color: #e1e1e1;
    }

.login {
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #5f9482;
    color: white;
}

    .login .textBox {
        width: 240px;
    }


    .login #divButton {
        padding: 4px;
        text-align: right;
    }

.chatRoom {
    width: 230px;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
}

    .chatRoom .title {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: #d7e5e4;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #5f9482;
        /*font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: #d7e5e4;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #5f9482;*/
    }

    .chatRoom .content {
        height: 300px;
        clear: both;
    }

        .chatRoom .content .chatWindow {
            float: right;
            width: 230px;
            height: 300px;
            border-left: solid 1px #5f9482;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

            .chatRoom .content .chatWindow .message {
                padding: 4px;
            }

                .chatRoom .content .chatWindow .message .userName {
                    font-weight: bold;
                }

        .chatRoom .content .users {
            float: right;
            width: 230px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

            .chatRoom .content .users .user {
                display: block;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 4px;
                background-color: #f9f9f9;
                border-bottom: solid 1px #5f9482;
            }

            .chatRoom .content .users .loginUser {
                display: block;
                padding: 4px;
                color: gray;
                border-bottom: solid 1px #5f9482;
            }

            .chatRoom .content .users .user:hover {
                background-color: #e1e1e1;
            }

    .chatRoom .messageBar {
        border-top: solid 1px gray;
        padding: 4px;
    }

        .chatRoom .messageBar .textbox {
            width: 230px;
        }

.disconnect {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #ffcbcb;
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}


.draggable {
    position: absolute;
    border: #5f9482 solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}

    .draggable .header {
        cursor: move;
        background-color: #e8eff0;
        border-bottom: #181f24 solid 1px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .draggable .selText {
        color: black;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .draggable .messageArea {
        width: 250px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #4cb6cb;
        border-bottom: #4cb6cb solid 1px;
    }

        .draggable .messageArea .message {
            padding: 4px;
            color:azure;
        }

    .draggable .buttonBar {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 4px;
    }

        .draggable .buttonBar .msgText {
            width: 172px;
        }

        .draggable .buttonBar .button {
            margin-left: 4px;
            width: 55px;
        }


.ui-draggable:not(.ui-draggable-dragging) .ui-widget-content .draggable {
    cursor: none;
}


.bg-light {
    background-color: #e8eff0;
    color: #788188;
}

    .bg-light.dk, .bg-light .dk {
        background-color: #e0eaec;
    }

/*.vbox > section.w-f-md {
    bottom: 60px;
}*/


/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}

Weather.css

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.wcard {
    width: 15rem;
    /*max-width: 15rem;
    max-height: 15rem;*/
    height: 10rem;
    /*background: #fff;*/
    /*margin: 2em auto;
    border-radius: .2em;*/
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.city {
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    float: left;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.card-img-left {
    width: 7rem;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
            }

.desc {
    width: 7rem;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -0.4em;
    margin-left: -0.2em;
           }


.temp {
    float: right;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin-top: -0.6em;
    margin-right: -1.3em;
    color: #fff;
}


.wind {
    float: right;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: -13em;
    margin-right: -6.4em;
    color: #fff;
}

.variations {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -2em;
}

.mph {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't think this is responsive because you didn't build it that way. I don't see any media queries in your css, which is typically how responsive development is done.

Comment: I am totally confused with asp.net mvc bootstrap. This is my first project with MVC. Do I need to create a different layout and partial views for mobile view? Is there any sites I can learn about bootstrap with asp.net mvc especially with regards to parial pages?

Comment: I want to do something like this page(header,footer,left sidebar,rightbar) using bootstrap https://pixinvent.com/stack-responsive-bootstrap-4-admin-template/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template/layout-content-detached-right-sticky-sidebar.html#

Comment: It sounds like the problem isn't with your code as much as you just don't know how to do this. You can certainly try to learn all of those things at the same time, but that can be very difficult. My recommendation would be to break the things up into bits of functionality to learn them in limited test cases. C#, MVC, ASP.net, Bootstrap, responsive design, etc... Whatever you don't know on that list try to learn separately. There are many good courses and sources to learn these, but you will be much happier in the long run if you don't try to learn them all at the same time.